# Как навесить событие на динамически создаваемый div в js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Есть плагин для mce 3.5 который создает div с классом `.incut.` Плагин представляет из себя кнопку который генерирует блок, представленный в сниппете ниже. Нуобходимо после создания этого блока навесить на него два события: `mouseenter` и `mouseleave`. Сначала я прочел про `live()` и его сегодняшний аналог `on`. Сделал вот такое:

```js
//функция вешает обработчики событий при наведении мыши и вызывает функцию
//создания элемента для удаления вырезки
function AddHoverButton() {
  const incut = document.querySelectorAll(".incut");
  [].forEach.call(incut, function(item) {
    item.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
      prependAndUncuteInsertEl(event.type, item);
    });
    item.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event) {
      prependAndUncuteInsertEl(event.type, item);
    });
  });
}

//функция элемент для удаления врезки из текста
function prependAndUncuteInsertEl(type, element) {
  const iElement = document.createElement("i");
  iElement.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove";
  iElement.id = "deletingItem";
  if (type === "mouseenter") {
    element.prepend(iElement);
  } else if (type === "mouseleave") {
    const itemToDelete = document.getElementById("deletingItem");
    itemToDelete.remove();
    return false;
  }
  deleteInsertText(iElement, element);
}

//функция удаляет вставленный текст по нажатию на createdItem
function deleteInsertText(createdItem, elemToDelete) {
  createdItem.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    elemToDelete.parentNode.removeChild(elemToDelete);
  });
}

$(document).on("mouseenter", ".incut", function(event) {
  prependAndUncuteInsertEl(event.type, this);
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", ".incut", function(event) {
  prependAndUncuteInsertEl(event.type, this);
});
```

```css
.incut.left {
  border-right: 2px solid #c0c0c0;
  border-left: none;
  float: right;
  margin: 8px 20px 8px 0px;
}

.incut {
  width: 330px;
  position: relative;
}

.incut.left a {
  float: left;
}

.incut a {
  float: right;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 314px;
}

.incut img {
  width: 314px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

P {
  margin: 5px 0px 7px 0px;
}

#deletingItem {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#deletingItem::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 0.5em;
  height: 100px;
  width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(255, 246, 246, 1);
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="incut left">
  <a title="«Терранову» и «Шоколадницу» во Владивостоке закрыли по решению суда" href="https://primamedia.ru/news/693791/" data-mce-href="https://primamedia.ru/news/693791/"><img src="http://primamedia.ru/f/266x136/1507/1506378.jpg" alt="" data-mce-src="http://primamedia.ru/f/266x136/1507/1506378.jpg">«Терранову» и «Шоколадницу» во Владивостоке закрыли по решению суда</a>
</div>
```

Это работает, например, на [codepen](https://codepen.io/Clasen00/pen/xjaagm) и тут, на SO (прыгает, правда). Но в случае, если DOM построен, а элемента на который нужно навесить обработчик еще нет, то данные события не срабатывают и крестик не появляется. Я решил сделать через DOMMutations. Код получился вот таким:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  //функция вешает обработчики событий при наведении мыши и вызывает функцию
  //создания элемента для удаления вырезки
  function AddHoverButton() {
    const incut = document.querySelectorAll(".incut");
    [].forEach.call(incut, function(item) {
      item.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
        prependAndUncuteInsertEl(event.type, item);
      });
      item.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event) {
        prependAndUncuteInsertEl(event.type, item);
      });
    });
  }

  //функция элемент для удаления врезки из текста
  function prependAndUncuteInsertEl(type, element) {
    const iElement = document.createElement("i");
    iElement.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove";
    iElement.id = "deletingItem";
    if (type === "mouseenter") {
      element.prepend(iElement);
    } else if (type === "mouseleave") {
      const itemToDelete = document.getElementById("deletingItem");
      itemToDelete.remove();
      return false;
    }
    deleteInsertText(iElement, element);
  }

  //функция удаляет вставленный текст по нажатию на createdItem
  function deleteInsertText(createdItem, elemToDelete) {
    createdItem.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      elemToDelete.parentNode.removeChild(elemToDelete);
    });
  }

  // Select the node that will be observed for mutations
  var targetNode = document.querySelector(
    ".mceIframeContainer.mceFirst.mceLast"
  );
  console.log(targetNode instanceof Node);
  // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
  var config = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true
  };

  // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
  var callback = function(mutationsList) {
    for (var mutation of mutationsList) {
      if (mutation.type == "childList") {
        $(document).on("mouseenter", ".incut", function(event) {
          prependAndUncuteInsertEl(event.type, this);
        });

        $(document).on("mouseleave", ".incut", function(event) {
          prependAndUncuteInsertEl(event.type, this);
        });
      } else if (mutation.type == "attributes") {
        $(document).on("mouseenter", ".incut", function(event) {
          prependAndUncuteInsertEl(event.type, this);
        });

        $(document).on("mouseleave", ".incut", function(event) {
          prependAndUncuteInsertEl(event.type, this);
        });
      }
    }
  };

  // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
  var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

  // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
  observer.observe(targetNode, config);
};
```

```css
.incut.left {
  border-right: 2px solid #c0c0c0;
  border-left: none;
  float: right;
  margin: 8px 20px 8px 0px;
}

.incut {
  width: 330px;
  position: relative;
}

.incut.left a {
  float: left;
}

.incut a {
  float: right;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 314px;
}

.incut img {
  width: 314px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

P {
  margin: 5px 0px 7px 0px;
}

#deletingItem {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#deletingItem::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 0.5em;
  height: 100px;
  width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(255, 246, 246, 1);
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="mceIframeContainer mceFirst mceLast">
  <div class="incut left">
    <a title="«Терранову» и «Шоколадницу» во Владивостоке закрыли по решению суда" href="https://primamedia.ru/news/693791/" data-mce-href="https://primamedia.ru/news/693791/"><img src="http://primamedia.ru/f/266x136/1507/1506378.jpg" alt="" data-mce-src="http://primamedia.ru/f/266x136/1507/1506378.jpg">«Терранову» и «Шоколадницу» во Владивостоке закрыли по решению суда</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Тут я использовал  `window.onload`, поскольку в переменную `targetNode` не попадает узел и возвращался `null`, т.к файл в котором лежит данный файл загружался быстрее плагина `tinymc`. Теперь я получаю в консоль на моменте 
`console.log(targetNode instanceof Node);` `true`, и поставленный мною `breakpoint` говорит, что до `observer.observe(targetNode, config);` дело доходит, но вот почему то все равно при добавлении элемента на него не навешиваются обработчики событий и ничего не работает.

Как можно исправить данный код, чтобы он работал так, как работает первый сниппет (с уже созданным элементом)?

**UPD**: возможно, вам станет интересна структура DOM дерева, вот она:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы хотите на странице навесить обработчик на элемент внутри `iframe` что ли?

Comment: ну да, а почему нет? он же доступен через `document.querySelector`

Comment: возьмите ваш первый кусок кода, и создайте на его основе минимальный пример для воспроизведения проблемы.

Comment: @teran реализовал пример) второй сниппет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Придется ответить на свой собственный вопрос. В общем, с чем пришлось столкнуться: `iframe` загружался сильно позже основной страницы, из за этого не работало даже событие `DOMContentLoaded`, срабатывало только `window.onload`. В общем, сделал вот так:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $(document.getElementById("cont_ifr").contentWindow.document).ready(function(
    e
  ) {
    //переопределяю документ, чтобы можно было работать в локальном контексте iframe 
    var document = this.getElementById("cont_ifr").contentWindow.document;
    var cssLink = document.createElement("link");
    cssLink.href =
      //а тут я вставляю в iframe bootstrap ибо верстка для меня недосягаема
      "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css";
    cssLink.rel = "stylesheet";
    cssLink.type = "text/css";
    this.getElementById("cont_ifr").contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(
      cssLink
    );

    //функция элемент для удаления врезки из текста
    function prependAndUncuteInsertEl(type, element) {
      const iElement = document.createElement("i");
      iElement.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove";
      iElement.id = "deletingItem";
      if (type === "mouseenter") {
        element.prepend(iElement);
      } else if (type === "mouseleave") {
        const itemToDelete = document.getElementById("deletingItem");
        itemToDelete.remove();
        return false;
      }
      deleteInsertText(iElement, element);
    }

    //функция удаляет вставленный текст по нажатию на createdItem
    function deleteInsertText(createdItem, elemToDelete) {
      createdItem.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        elemToDelete.parentNode.removeChild(elemToDelete);
      });
    }

    $(document).on("mouseenter", ".incut", function(event) {
      prependAndUncuteInsertEl(event.type, this);
    });

    $(document).on("mouseleave", ".incut", function(event) {
      prependAndUncuteInsertEl(event.type, this);
    });
  });
};
```

Обратите внимание, что в `this` у нас теперь главный `document` всей страницы, а в `document` - локальный, который принадлежит нашему `iframe`. Как выглядит верстка представлено в вопросе, в самом низу.